Why 5 video streamings are created when Enable live media streaming in your Amazon Connect instance, not 2?
My understanding that when "Enable live media streaming in your Amazon Connect instance", 2 video streams will be created, 1 for from-customer and the other to-customer. Why there are 5 video streams created? How to tell which video stream is from-customer and which video stream is to-customer, what about the other 3 video streams?
Here is the link I followed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/enable-live-media-streams.html
